# How to deploy Content Processing Framework in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

I have a MarkLogic 7 database and I can install Content Processing Framework from the Admin Interface. After installing CPF I can load a Pipeline from file system and link it with a Domain.

I can perform the above mentioned operations from the Admin Interface **BUT** I need a way to deploy the CPF pipeline that I have created along with the CPF action modules.

**Is there any way to install and deploy the CPF pipeline with some kind of deployment script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth mentioning here too is [Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy). It has a very good deployment mechanism, capable of deploying against multiple versions of MarkLogic. It also provides means to configure, deploy, and remove CPF from an installation:

https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Working-with-CPF

It runs on top of Ruby, but you can create a jar out of it as well..

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

you will find scripting examples here

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/cpf

upcoming versions of MarkLogic will allow one to do this 100% with REST calls to management api

Comment: Till the time MarkLogic comes up with REST interface to management api I think I need to create XQuery scripts to create and CPF pipeline and somehow execute the QQuery script in the deployment process. Currently I am using Powershell scripts for deployment which create the MarkLogic database, foreset, app server using the Configuration Manager REST end point. Any suggestions on how should I execute the XQuery script(that creates the CPF pipeline) from the existing Powershell deployment scripts?

Comment: Old comment, but it's worth mentioning that as of MarkLogic 8, there is a REST interface to the Management API, including [management of CPF](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management/content-processing-framework-(cpf)).